# Handling elements generated by Javascript in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have several elements in my web page generated by JavaScript.
Here's an example of such content:

```
<input id="uploadfile01" type="file" onchange="change(1);" />
<input id="uploadfile02" type="file" onchange="change(2);" />
```

My question is:
How can I interact with these elements in the server side, (Asp.net) after a post?
(Since the elements were dynamically generated they do not exist in the original asp.net page)

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to do.

In this specific case I don't mind losing the controls content after a postback.
The problem is that in the server side I cannot detect the newly generated tags, (even if they have content they don't show up)

Unfortunately you solution appear to be the way to go.
Thanks. ;)

Comment: Found a solution to my own answer here: [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/post/2009/05/31/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-Dynamic-FileUpload-Controls-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that would be possible.....if i am not mistaken you want to give the option  to attach multiple files. i think it would be better to place a set number of fileupload controls and set there **display** to **none** and you can use javascript to show them.

i know that this is not what you are looking for but after a postback the controls will be lost and even if they are added again they will lose there contents.(had you been generating them through code behind)